# HTML5 video tearing/stretching - Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video, ogg

I have an MP4 video which I have made into a .ogg using Firefogg.
Viewed by themselves, the videos are completely fine.
However when I view the .ogg in firefox via HTML5 -> `<video>` I am getting weird tearing at the top of the screen, as seen below.

This is what the .ogg looks like when viewed in firefox.
[image]

This is what the .ogg looks like when viewed in FLV player.
[image]

These are the settings ive used for creating the .ogg[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay><source src="content/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="content/video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg"></video>
```

There is no CSS directly affecting this, however it does lie inside a bootstrap container, but so does the .mp4 version and it does not have this issue.

Even if someone has a reference to another, reliable, way to create .ogg / .ogv files that would be very helpful as maybe the encoder is the issue?

Thanks,

**Update:**
Firefox 6.0 does not have this issue. I am running Firefox 32.0.3.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a link to where we could see the issue? Firefogg is as good as any ogv encoder in my experience.

Comment: To round up this question from ages ago. I reviewed this issue today and it appears that it has resolved itself, so my assumption is that there must of been a bug with the version of Firefox I was running at time of posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To round up this question from ages ago. 
I reviewed this issue today and it appears that it has resolved itself, so my assumption is that there must of been a bug with the version of Firefox I was running at time of posting.
 Sorry for the unsatisfying answer.